# How to send message to tagged channel?

Tags: bots, embed, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a command that sends an embed to the tagged channel by command for example **!embed #games Cool game**

So, I was trying with `args[0].id` and `embedargs[0].id` and normal args and embedargs, but bot still doesn't know where to send it and throws an error.

Thank you in advance for any help! <3

Comment: You can take a look at [`message.mentions.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=channels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're after:

```
message.mentions.channels.first().send("Message Content", embed);
```

This looks for the first mentioned channel, then sends a message to it. You'll just have to split the first two parts of the message to receive your embed, like this:

```
var embedText = message.content.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');
// Remove the first 2 Words ("!embed <#channel>")
var embed = new RichEmbed()
  .setTitle(embedText);
//Create the Embed using this as the title
message.mentions.channels.first().send("Message Content", embed);
//Send the Embed
```